# Create a React component for each element on JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase

I need consultation with rendering React components for each element in JSON (in this case - Firebase database).
I'm trying to create an array of book's data and push it to an array **bookKeysArray** which then I will use for mapping.

As a result I get error that component **ListOfUserBooks** doesn't return anything (*bookComponent* is undefined).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
function ListOfUserBooks(props) {
    currentUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    userBooksDataRef = firebase.database().ref('booksData/').child(currentUserId);
    let bookKeysArray = [],
        bookComponent;

    userBooksDataRef.once('value')
            .then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                    bookKey = childSnapshot.key;
                    bookData = childSnapshot.val();
                    description = bookData.description;
                    ...

                    let bookDataArray = [description, ...];
                    bookKeysArray.push(bookDataArray);

                    bookComponent = bookKeysArray.map((book, index) => {
                            <ListOfUserBooks_ListView key = {index}
                                                       description = {book.description}
                                                       .../>
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
     return bookComponent;
};
```

**Firebase data structure**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data/data-structure?

Comment: This seems to be an async problem. `bookComponent` is returned before it is assigned within the `then` function. Could possibly be solved by using async/await (https://javascript.info/async-await) rather than callbacks.

Comment: I don't think Render functions are allowed to be aysnc. That's why all React docs suggest loading data in `componentDidMount` and then updating state on success to cause a re-render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution of the `.then` is asynchronous. So you are actually returning `bookComponent` before having even populated it. In react development operations such retrieving data from FireBase are executed in a lifecycle hook to populate the state and then render it. You can easily accomplish this using a class component:

```
class ListOfUserBooks extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.state = { bookKeysArray: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    currentUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    userBooksDataRef = firebase.database().ref('booksData/').child(currentUserId);
    userBooksDataRef.once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
         bookKeysArray = []
         snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
           bookKey = childSnapshot.key;
           bookData = childSnapshot.val();
           description = bookData.description;
           ...
           bookKeysArray.push([description, ...]);
         })
         this.setState({ bookKeysArray })
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.bookKeysArray.map((book, index) => {
      return <ListOfUserBooks_ListView key = {index} .../>
    });
  }
}
```